# How can I get all shape layers where their names include specific word?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I have this function which gets all shape layers of a document...

```
function getAllShapeLayersData() {
    var lyrs = [];
    try {
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        var layers = 0
    } catch (e) {
        var layers = 1;
    };

    while (true) {
        ref = new ActionReference();
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);
        try {
            var desc = executeActionGet(ref);
        } catch (err) {
            break;
        }

        var lyr = {};
        lyr.type = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerKind"));
        lyr.name = desc.getString(charIDToTypeID("Nm  "));
        lyr.id = desc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("layerID"));

        if (lyr.type == 4) {
            var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0);
            if (adj.hasKey(stringIDToTypeID("color"))) {
                var curColor = new SolidColor();
                curColor.rgb.red = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("red"));
                curColor.rgb.green = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("grain"));
                curColor.rgb.blue = adj.getObjectValue(stringIDToTypeID("color")).getUnitDoubleValue(stringIDToTypeID("blue"));
                lyr.color = curColor;
                lyrs.push(lyr);
            }
        }
        layers++;
    }
    return lyrs
};
```

I changes to this `if (lyr.name == "Something") {` instead of `if (lyr.type == 4) {` so now I managed to get all layers by the name "Something". I tried something like this `if (lyr.name.includes("Stitches")) {` so to get all layers where their names contains the word "Something", but I get an error!!!

So, how can I get **all shape layers** where their **names contains specific word**? In other words, first, how can I use `if (lyr.type == 4) {` and `if (lyr.name.includes("Stitches")) {` together and second what is the correct syntax of the "include" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop uses ancient JS engine, something like ES3, so there's no `.include()`. You can use `String.indexOf()` instead:

```
if (lyr.name.indexOf("Stitches") !== -1) {
    //"Stitches" is found in the name
}
```

Comment: Stops here `var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0);` and says "The requested property does not exist".

Comment: did you remove `if (lyr.type == 4)`?

Comment: Yes... Should I have them both?

Comment: Of course, otherwise it's going to try to get a property that only exists on Shape layers (that are type 4 in PS nomenclature).

Comment: And what is the syntax for double if?

Comment: Syntax is `if (condition1 && condition2) {}`. That's quite a basic thing, if you're asking this I'd recommend to take a course on JavaScript first.

Comment: No, I am asking because I already tried that and I got error!!!

Comment: Error in double condition? it's working in my case :O

Comment: Please edit your post with the code that produces the error, otherwise it's impossible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: No it's okay now... Obviously was my fault, it was a typo. Sorry and thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `lyr.name.match("string")` :)

Comment: I get the same error as with Sergey example. It stops here var adj = desc.getList(stringIDToTypeID("adjustment")).getObjectValue(0); and says "The requested property does not exist".

Comment: sergey already provide double if! hope it resolved your issue :D

Comment: Your example "works" too!!! Thank you very much!!! It was my fault, I had a typo in "double if". I accepted Sergeys answer as correct because he answered first, by seconds. :)

Comment: don't worry at least i also learned something from Sergey :D